# How can I read the latest entry in Kafka?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I'm using the [.NET Client library](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) from Confluent.

I need to connect to a topic and read back *the last message* written in it. I cannot use an absolute offset because I do not know it, and logical offsets do not appear to help. In particular `Offset.End` puts the *cursor* just *after* the last entry, hence any subsequent read call (like `Consume`) would return either a newer entry, if available, or `null`, but not the latest available at the very moment of the call.

I'm actually wondering if it is a sensible use case in Kafka parlance (I'm quite new to it). I found a few examples of similar cases, but nothing explaining this one, and I cannot find a good way to adapt those other cases to mine. I also tried to do some arithmetics with cursors, like summing/subtracting them (i.e. `Offset.End-1` or `Offset.End-new Offset(1)`), but what I get is clearly abnormal cursors which cannot be used. Which makes me think: why `+` and `-` have been defined at all for `Offset` if then they allow you to craft invalid values? But that is a different story.

Comment: I was able to achieve something good enough using `OffsetsForTimes`, it's not perfect but for my goals it's ok. It would still be interesting though if there was a simpler and nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

set the `auto.offset.reset` property to latest and your consumer will always read the last entry.

Comment: I believe that's not correct, I actually tried, and if you set it to latest the *cursor* goes beyond the latest entry ready for new messages, so you do not read the last message currently present on the log. Furthermore I think `auto.offset.reset` is meant to be used for a consumer group that hasn't committed any messages yet, which is  not my case.

Comment: If you want to read the latest record in kafka then setting `auto.offset.reset` is the property as the documentation explains https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html 

However you might want to also disable the `auto.commit` property as well so you don't lose records as they are being processed.

Comment: This in not what I see as behavior when I try, and I do see several people around describing what I see. For example quoting from [Kafka: the definitive guide (O'Reilly)](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html):  *The default is “latest,” which means that lacking a valid offset, the consumer will start reading from the newest records (* ***records that were written after the consumer started running*** *).*  The official docs you reference are actually vague when defining what *latest* means.